# Cloudinary jQuery Upload Authorization

Tags: jquery, authentication, client-side, cdn, cloudinary

I'm using Force.com Apex and VF trying to utilize Cloudinary for some content management. I'm stuck on the following from Chrome (not sure why it shows 'undefined' as Cloud Name is defined in JS):

```
POST https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/undefined/upload 401 (Unauthorized)    ......    api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/undefined/upload:1
```

At a point of frustration would really appreciate any assistance. Here's the code (note comments):

- The APEX

:

```
public String getCldSig() {

        Datetime d = datetime.now();
        Long uxtime = d.getTime() / 1000; //method provides epoch/unix time
        String apisec = '<some_secret>';
        String serial = 'callback=<some_url>&public_id=<some_id>&timestamp=' + uxtime + apisec;
        Blob sha = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA1', Blob.valueOf(serial));
        String sig = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(sha); //perhaps I need to do UTF-8
        String jsoSerial = '{"public_id":"<some_Id>",';
        jsoSerial += '"timestamp":"'+ uxtime + '",'; 
        jsoSerial += '"callback":"<some_url>",';  //maybe an issue with hosting the CORS html on a VF page.
        jsoSerial += '"signature":"' + sig + '",'; 
        jsoSerial += '"api_key":"<some_key>"}';
        return jsoSerial.escapeHtml3(); //seems to be the right escape output HTML
}
```

- The Javascript/jQuery:

  ```
                  $.cloudinary.config({"api_key":"<some_key>", "cloud_name":"<some_id>"});                       
                  $('.cloudinary-fileupload')
                    .fileupload({ 
                      dropZone: ".sceneUpBtn",
                      progress: function (e, data) {
                        $(".progress").text("Uploading... " + Math.round((data.loaded * 100.0) / data.total) + "%");
                      }
                    });
                  $('.cloudinary-fileupload').bind('fileuploadstart', function(e){
                    $('.sceneUpPrev').html('Upload started...');
                  });                     
                  $('.cloudinary-fileupload').bind('fileuploadfail', function(e){
                    $('.sceneUpPrev').html($.cloudinary.error); //**due to lack of documentation don't know how to get any specific error message using the jQuery library. Would expect messages similar to AWS S3
                  });     
                  $('.cloudinary-fileupload').bind('cloudinarydone', function(e, data) {  
                      $('.sceneUpPrev').html(
                         $.cloudinary.image(data.result.public_id, 
                             { format: data.result.format, version: data.result.version, 
                               crop: 'scale', width: 200 }));    
                      $('.image_public_id').val(data.result.public_id);    
                      return true;
                  });
  ```

Input HTML:

```
<input class="cloudinary-fileupload" 
data-cloudinary-field="upref" 
data-form-data="&quot;public_id&quot;:&quot;<some_id>&quot;,&quot;timestamp&quot;:&quot;1372282433&quot;,&quot;callback&quot;:&quot;<some_url>&quot;,&quot;signature&quot;:&quot;<some_sig>&quot;,&quot;api_key&quot;:&quot;<some_key>&quot;}" 
id="sceneUpload" 
name="file" 
type="file">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With much help from Tal at Cloudinary, I have reached success! I'll recap the solution:

1. Do not instantiate Cloudinary's library in $(document).ready(), instead just plug it in 
   directly within script section

   ```
       <script type="text/javascript">             
       $.cloudinary.config({"api_key":"<key>","cloud_name":"<cloud_name>"});
   ```
2. Instantiate the formData with the FileUpload widget, this ensures fileUpload
   loads your json send params (it's a timing issue).

   ```
                       $('.cloudinary-fileupload').fileupload({ 
                           formData : <unescaped json params>,
                           dropZone: $('.sceneUpBtn'),                             
                           dataType: 'json',
                           done: function (e, data) {
                               $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                                   $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#filename');
                               });
                               },
                           progressall: function (e, data) {
                               var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                               $('.sceneUpBar').css('width',progress + '%');
                           }
                   });
   ```
3. Match signature params to json params sent to server. In Apex sign and return json as such:

   ```
   public String getCloudinarySig() {
       Datetime d = datetime.now();
       Long uxtime = d.getTime() / 1000; //epoch unix time method in force.com
       String apisec = '<secret>';
       String serial = 'callback=<cors url>&timestamp=' + uxtime + apisec; //Signature needs params here need to match json params below
       Blob sha = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA1', Blob.valueOf(serial)); //Sha1 digest
       String sig = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(sha); //Hex conversion
       String jsoSerial = '{';
       jsoSerial += '"api_key":"<key>",'; //these json params need to match signature params above     
       jsoSerial += '"<CORS_url>",';                   
       jsoSerial += '"signature":"' + sig + '",';  
       jsoSerial += '"timestamp":'+ uxtime; 
       jsoSerial += '}';
       return jsoSerial;
   ```

   }

Happy to answer any questions...

Comment: could you please explain your second point a bit more? Have you tried populating JSON params dynamically or are you instantiating them on the page load?

Comment: My original mistake was populating JSON params directly into the INPUT's "data-form-data" attribute. The FileUpload widget was instantiating before the "data-form-data" was being set, as a result the authentication failed because the "data-form-data" was blank when being passed to Cloudinary.

To resolve, you should not populate "data-form-data", instead populate the "formData" parameter (same difference) when loading the FileUpload widget.

Comment: Thanks, I made the same mistake of updating data-form-data attribute directly. The only thing I would like to add for those lazy ones who only look for answers at the stack overflow and do not read the documentation - `formData` parameter in `fileupload` function expects JSON hash (or JavaScript object) and **NOT** a serialised JSON string

Comment: Correct, must be a JSON object

Comment: one more question - how did you handle CORS callback? I've used   the path that I got from VisualForce URLFOR function ('/resource/1374488763000/Cloudinary_plugin/html/cloudinary_cors.html'), however this fails in IE10. Curious how you handled this problem.

Comment: Actually created a dedicated VF page and plugged in the CORS script and referenced that VF page in the Auth and JSON.

Answer (score 2):

The "undefined" part of the POST url means that Cloudinary's jQuery library could not determine the cloud_name when the POST url was generated.
Most likely this is because the $.cloudinary.config function is called too late. Please move this call outside of $(document).ready or similar constructs.

One more (unrelated) point - The selector in the second line is missing a '.' It should read $('.cloudinary-fileupload')

Comment: Thank you, so I corrected both points at least some progress was made, but I am still receiving from Chrome:

    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<some_id>/upload

Comment: Also could you provide the exact order of all the base js includes needed.

Comment: More errors I see:
1) The name of the input field should be file (not files).
2) How is data-form-data initialized? Is it in JS or is it in the HTML? If in JS can you send the code used to do the initialization?

Can you post a gist with the full HTML generated?

Comment: The correct order of includes:
jquery.js
jquery.ui.widget.js
jquery.iframe-transport.js
jquery.fileupload.js
jquery.cloudinary.js

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but if by initialization you mean how does it get the escaped JSON value, then it is being set by an Apex getter method in the HTML. In Force.com Apex you enter the "merge syntax" {!CldSig} as the value in the HTML and on server load it gets the value.

Thank you for the order of includes, they match my current order.

Comment: Can you please post a gist with the full HTML generated?

Comment: The value of the data-form-data field is HTML encoded twice (&amp;quot; should have been of &quot;). Maybe try to remove the escapeHtml3 call?

Comment: Yes I see that, I think that happened during the gist post, the code itself doesn't have that. As an update, I'm still stuck on this, but I did realize something basic, the return json says "Unknown API Key". As a result I'm looking closely at the Cloudinary library initialization/parameters, but nothing so far. Also doing is there a reliable way to validate the signature outside of the REST call?

Comment: Also would the timezone on the uxtime be an issue?

Comment: @TalLevAmi Update -- Signature was validated against example in your Documentation, so I can confirm the signature is being hashed correctly. Can the json be verified somehow on your end if I provide you the whole html, signature/keys and all?

Comment: Yes. A complete rendered html will be very helpful. Please open a support ticket by sending an email to support@cloudinary.com, we'll be able to help more there.